# Anaconda3 with existing Python Installation

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have Installed Anaconda3 (64bit) and I already have a Python 2.7 Installation on the default path (Windows 10). When I start the python.exe from the new Anaconda Installation, I cannot import numpy, as it fails to load multiarray.
Is it possible to have different python istallation at the same time? If yes, how can I prevent python from loading old files / modules and only import from the current environment?
Thanks!

Comment: You definitely installed _Anaconda_ and not Miniconda? Also, you're definitely navigating into the Anaconda directory and launching the shell from in there?

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: When I double click on python.exe in anaconda3 folder, the error occurs. Also if I add the environment variable 'pythonpath' as C:/users/user/Anaconda3/python.exe it is still unable to import numpy

Comment: Anaconda installs so many other packages... can you load other packages that come with anaconda?

Comment: Anything relevant in [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272)? Are you able to upgrade the numpy installation?

Comment: Yes I can import all the packages except for the ones requiring numpy. Also I upgraded using conda upgrade numpy, no improvement

Comment: Going through the [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272) , it seems like anaconda messes up with the DLLs and loads some old .dlls. If I create a new conda environment with python 3.6. and install numpy in there, the import works. I am not sure how to solve this properls tbh.

Comment: Try uninstall from the base environment and a fresh install? Use the hammer approach and cross fingers :) you may lose pandas in the process

Comment: Unfortunately I built some modules based on numpy (like opencv) from source and I'd prefer not losing them... So might not be the best idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem after all. After reinstalling the module I discovered that

`conda uninstall`

leaves a version of numpy behind. `conda install` would always install two versions, one hidden in the file explorer. I deleted both using `conda remove` AND `pip remove`and reinstalled numpy using `pip install numpy` (instead of using conda) and it finally solved my issues!

Comment: That's a little worrisome... conda is supposed to solve these problems, not create them!